# Unable to understand this jquery code

Tags: jquery

I recently came through a website and checked its functionality. I visited their main javascript file and came through this code.

```
    var featureIconHolder = $(".feature-icon-holder", "#features-links-holder");

    featureIconHolder.on("click",function(){
        featureIconHolder.removeClass("opened");
        $(this).addClass("opened");
        $(".show-details","#features-holder").removeClass("show-details");
        $(".feature-d"+$(this).data("id"), "#features-holder").addClass("show-details");
    });
```

I am unable to understand how he stores two things in one variable at a time. Also what is **$(this).data("id")** . Will please someone explain me this code in detail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "he stores two things in one variable at a time" - do you mean `$(".feature-icon-holder", "#features-links-holder")` ?

Comment: yes, he stores. but what i really does in plain english will you please explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specific questions:

```
var featureIconHolder = $(".feature-icon-holder", "#features-links-holder");
```

Here's the documentation link for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1
The two arguments here are selector and context. What this does is find all elements of class `feature-icon-holder` that are descendents of the element with ID `features-links-holder`. This constructs an array-like object that contains 0+ elements depending on how many matched.

> what is `$(this).data("id")`

Inside the click handler, `this` is the element that has been clicked. So `$(this)` is a jQuery object for that element, and [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) reads or stores values against an element. It's then used to construct another selector by concatenating strings.

---

This changes the displayed 'feature' based on the icon clicked. What it does:

1. Find all elements with class `feature-icon-holder` inside the element with ID `feature-links-holder`.
2. Set up a click handler on all of these elements:

   1. removes the 'opened' class from all of these icons, i.e. it clears 'opened' from the previously open element. The opened class is probably a highlight around the icon.
   2. sets the 'opened' class on this icon, presumably highlighting it.
   3. clears the 'show-details' class from any elements inside ID `feature-holder` that currently has the class; again there's probably only one of these, the currently displayed feature
   4. adds the 'show-details' class to the element inside `feature-holder` that has a class name matching the ID stored with the icon clicked. This will presumably show the feature elsewhere on the page.